# How can I obscure a screen but still view mouse and click?

Tags: windows

I'm looking for a way to make my screen hidden but still be able to see the location of the mouse and perform clicks within a program.

If you're wondering why the hell I would want to do that, I'm the world record holder for a video game and I want to try playing it with obscured vision, but blindfolding doesn't work because I still need to somehow track the relative location of the mouse or I'll get nowhere.

Comment: You can get the mouse's X,Y co-ordinates on the screen maybe?

Comment: @Vinayak I'm not sure if you understand the question.  What I'm looking for is a way to essentially make the screen black (or any color) except for my mouse cursor, and still be able to play a game that involves a lot of clicking.

Comment: Does the game use a custom cursor or the system cursor? If it uses the system cursor then you should be able to adjust the gamma of the game independently from the cursor. If not I'd guess the best way to do this is to make an app which fakes it.

Comment: If it is an HTML 5 game this would work as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569775/how-do-i-find-the-dom-node-that-is-at-a-given-x-y-position-hit-test

Comment: @krowe I'm pretty sure it uses a cutsom cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never thought there'd be a tool out there that could do this, but I guess I was wrong.

[WindowShades](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/WindowShades-Download-166492.html) is what you want. Use the Softpedia mirror or just [click this link.](http://www.softpedia.com/dyn-postdownload.php/43a84e01ccf98e83835c33e18ae61ead/540bd96c/28a5c/4/1)

Use the following color settings:

```
Saturation : 0%
Value      : 0%
Opacity    : 100%
```

Note: Keep the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key pressed to exit the program. You'll need this if you can't see anything on the screen.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which game are you trying this out for?

Comment: Spy Fox 2.  You can see my world record run here [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WuyaIRFch_A)